# Hugo Docsy image path referencing with multiple languages

Tags: internationalization, markdown, hugo, docsy

I am the static site generator [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) with the theme [Docsy](https://www.docsy.dev), but I am having difficulty providing the correct path so Hugo can find my images?

I read Hugo's content organization will search for an image either in the [Page Bundle](https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/#page-bundles) or in the project's `static` directory.  [See Hugo Directory Structure: static](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/directory-structure/).

I am using the Page Bundle organization for the images in my project.
The path to my images is:
`My_Hugo_Docsy_Project/content/en/docs/My_Page_Bundle/assets/image_file.jpg`

I am using regular markdown to include the images, but this does not work:

`![Image1](/assets/image_file.jpg)`

I believe Docsy's multiple language feature (internationalization) is causing the hangup, which nests the content directory structure by language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Docsy's default config.toml, sets `contentDir = "content/en"`.](https://www.docsy.dev/docs/language/)

[Setting `contentDir` effectively changes the "site root"](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/) for Page Bundled resources like images.  The "site root" directory is where Hugo would start to look for `image_file.jpg`.

```
#Hugo root directory when contentDir = "content/en"
`My_Hugo_Docsy_Project/content/en/

#Hugo root directory when contentDir = “content”
My_Hugo_Docsy_Project/content
```

So the image path in the markdown would be:

`![Image1](/docs/My_Page_Bundle/assets/image_file.jpg)`

Comment: At a glance, I don't see how that config impacts you. You're using page bundles, so you should be able to reference the images with a relative path, e.g. `assets/image_file.jpg`. Note the dropped leading slash. Just a hunch though, not tested.

Comment: tested the markup you suggested `assets/image_file.jpg` w/o the leading "/" it resulted in broken jpg.  I definitely didn't anticipate the "contentDir" was adjusting the "site root" for Page Bundled resources.